# Get document source after executes client scripts

Tags: javascript, php, dom

Sorry for my English.

I want to copy the entire source code of an external website. I use library PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. But when I get souce, I get only  and in body only JS script.
How would I get the content of the site and then be able to select the div-content AFTER the javascript has populated it with the correct content? May be I can execute this JS code in my side?

Code of this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <title>...</title>
    <link href="shared/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/tv.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#fff;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">

<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://"+window.location.hostname+"/ajax/oficpaz.php",
    data: "do=js&sess=o3vjro76847f1e2uqebqr904a6&id=262575",
    success: function(data){
        jQuery("body").html(data);
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks You!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a headless browser like [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) or [slimer.js](http://www.slimerjs.org/)

Comment: Can You please explain more? How I can Access headless browser from php?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox, try selecting all the text on the page and then right-click -> view selection source.

Comment: I think he meant _programmatically_

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure there is no copyright or intellectual property right you are violating by copying someone else code directly.

Secondly there is AJAX on this page meaning you can copy the script but as you can see it post to a php page that may or may not contain HTML and JavaScript that you can copy but you will not be able to see any php script as this is executed on the server side.

This is a security feature of php. If you were able to see the php script you will also be able to see that websites database structure and any password and encryption keys etc.

So to answer your question. NO you won't be able to copy php script by viewing the source code in a browser. You need access to the server to download the php files and then you will be able to copy from them.

Comment: Actually that is not a "Security Feature" but just how PHP works. If you could see the PHP source, it would not have been executed.

Comment: But maybe I can create POST request from php to “https://"+window.location.hostname+"/ajax/oficpaz.php” and get text, which I can see in this page?